# jquery preventDefault() is not working sometimes in chrome

Tags: jquery, preventdefault

I am trying to prevent the default behavior of the enter key through `preventDefault()` but it is not working.Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#Last").keydown(function(event){
     if (event.keyCode==13) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Enter Pressed");
      }});

 $("#ffff").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Submit Button Clicked");
         });
});
```

and here is the html part

```
<form action="http://www.google.co.in">
First name: <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Al"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" id="Last" name="LastName" value="McCoy"><br>
<input type="button" value=" Next " id="validate">
<input id="ffff" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

So according to the code above it should only alert `Enter Pressed` if I press enter key on Last Name field, but it alerts both.Is there anything in the code wrong? Here is the link for the details [Js.do](http://js.do/code/76957)

Comment: working for me. please check console if there is any error

Comment: If the button isn't supposed to submit the form anyway, just change it's type to `button` instead of `submit`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t85c0sxz/

Comment: @adeneo :ya it is working fine in jsfiddle but why it is not working in chrome .FYI I am using this version of jQuery [link](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js)

Comment: I see your issue here is that you are setting alert() which is modal in keydown, it seems to block the `event.preventDefault()`, default behaviour is still fired. Using console (as you should), fixes it: http://jsfiddle.net/j2znquxf/

Comment: @A.Wolff Thank you for finding the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A. Wolff is correct that this occurs because of the alert() box. This is very very similar to an issue I had in C# and here is the explanation as to why it happens.

The main thread in Javascript pauses the execution of the specified function when `alert` is called. It does not, however pause execution of Javascript. So, your second event gets called even though the initial event never finished. This is why the `event.preventDefault()` does not work. If you run the code below with the console open, you should notice that `click` gets logged before the exit `keydown` gets logged.

The log output I get is:

```
Start KeyDown Function
Start Click Function
End Click Function
End KeyDown Function
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Last").keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      console.log('Start KeyDown Function');
      alert("Enter Pressed");
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('End KeyDown Function');
    }
  });

  $("#ffff").click(function(event) {
    console.log('Start Click Function');
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("Submit Button Clicked");
    console.log('End Click Function');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://www.google.co.in">
  First name:
  <input type="text" name="FirstName" value="Al">
  <br>Last name:
  <input type="text" id="Last" name="LastName" value="McCoy">
  <br>
  <input type="button" value=" Next " id="validate">
  <input id="ffff" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: :Thank you for your explanation .In fact I am a beginner to jQuery .So could you please suggest me any site or book to get all those details? I would be grateful.